# JsonServiceClient adding path to url

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm using a JsonServiceClient, initialized with the url parameter like:

```
  JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://dis.dat/whatever/coolService");

  client.Post(new MyRequest{ Foo = "bar"});
```

But when i check for the output url, I can see that the service used a different URL, more precisely

```
    http://dis.dat/whatever/coolService/json/reply/MyRequest
```

The request type is as simple as

```
    public class MyRequest
    {
        public string Foo {get; set;}
    }
```

Of course, I would like to prevent this behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should use [custom routes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing):

```
[Route("/")]
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. I didn't knew this would work also on outgoing POSTs