# unexpected http get request using JsonServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I am trying to make a json request on an external service, that would look like this :

GET request :

```
https://remotehost/path/mycount?foo=C&bar=21
```

response :

`{"count":1000}`

for this I use ServiceStack JsonServiceClient, which I like because you can pass a object as parameter. this makes it easy to use/read.

*Here is my code :*

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(classifiedSearchBaseURL);
var response = client.Get<CountResponse>(
                                                       new MyRequest
                                                           {
                                                               foo = "C",
                                                               bar = 21
                                                           });

class MyRequest
{

    public string foo { get; set; }
    public int bar { get; set; }
}

class CountResponse
{
    public string count;
}
```

But when debugging, instead of getting this http request to the server

```
GET /path/mycount?foo=C&bar=21
```

I am getting this

```
GET /path/json/reply/MyRequest?foo=C&bar=21
```

Any of you guys has an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [JsonServiceClient adding path to url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31402628/3744182). Can you confirm the solution there works for you?  I don't have ServiceStack installed where I am now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that I should use the Route attribute to the Request object

Following is the modified code

```
[ServiceStack.Route("/mycount")]
class MyRequest
{
   public string foo { get; set; }
   public int bar { get; set; }
}
```